# How to avoid losing vocal comp on Logic Pro X when recording another take?

Tags: voice, recording, homerecording, logic-pro, studio

In Logic Pro X when I record multiple takes and choose my comp selections. After already choosing the selections I want to come back and record another take, but then I lose my previous comp selections. How can I avoid losing my previous comp selections after recording a new vocal take.

As example, when I take 4 takes and have chosen the selections out of those 4 takes: [image]

When I take the 5th (after already making the comp choices). I loose my previous comp choices and the new take takes over fully.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When recording a take folder in Logic, you can create multiple "comps". Your first comp should be "Comp A". In your bottom image, if you click on the B next to the disclosure triangle, you will get a menu list of all you comps and each individual takes. Click on "Comp A" to revert to it.

Here's what I get after recording a new take:
[image]

Here's the menu showing my previous comp, individual takes, and other options:
[image]

Here's my reselected Comp A (after selecting "A - Comp A" from the above menu):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for correcting me and teaching me something new to boot today Bob! +1

Comment: A collector's item - it won't happen often, @John Belzaguy!